# Converting application/pdf, text/html data to multipart/form-data in datapower

Tags: javascript, xslt, multipartform-data, ibm-datapower

We have a scenario where we are recieving document as content-type application/pdf or text/html or text/xml data from first backend, which we need to pass to another backend which will accept the data only as multipart/form-data. I have attached my code snippet. Also how to set boundary value in datapower ?

The data is not reaching as form-data to second backend.

My Gateway code Snippet looks like this :

```
var urlopen = require('urlopen');
var sm = require('service-metadata');
var hm = require('service-metadata');
var ctx = session.name('message') || session.createContext('message');
session.input.readAsBuffer(function(error, buffer){
 if (error) {
   //an error occurred when parsing the content,
    throw error;
   }
var uuid = (session.name('message').getVar('uuid'));
var boundary = (session.name('message').getVar('boundary'));
var ctype = hm.current.get('Content-Type');

var options = {
target:'targeturl',
headers : hm.current.get(),
method: 'post',
data: boundary+ '\n' +" Content-Disposition:form-data; name="+'"'+"fileContent"+'"' + "hello.html" +'"\n' + "Content-Type: text/html" + '\n' + buffer.toString() +'\n' + boundary +'\n'
};

urlopen.open(options,function (error, response) {
if (error) {
session.output.write("openCallback error: " + error.errorMessage+"\n");
}
else {
 if (response.statusCode != 200) {

)
```

Comment: can anyone please suggest if you come across similar scenario and whether this integration is possible in DataPower

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but you will need to build the complete MIME form and set the correct headers for it.
E.g. the `Content-Type` has to be set something like:

```
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=' + boundary;
```

You will also need to add the MIME boundaries, like:

```
--my_fine_boundary_1234
Content-Disposition:form-data; name=HELLO

--my_fine_boundary_1234--
```

Your code doesn't reveal if `boundary` has the dashes `--` or not included but you need to add the starting dashes and the ending dashes and in the `content-type` header the dashes must NOT be included!
You should also use `\r\n` for new-lines in the MIME data.

See more about MIME standard here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt